# How to develop a GUI program that runs before Windows boots?

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, boot

I need to develop a software that runs before Windows boots. For example Acronis TrueImage or other imaging or partition manipulating software allow to boot to alternative environment, and they support quite nice graphical interface.

I know that one can develop a bootkit - but developing nice UI for it will require an enormous amount of work. Another approach is NT native app, but that doesn't support any kind of GUI too, besides has limited colors. Any ideas how Acronis or similar solutions work? Thank you

Comment: Several of those use "Windows Preinstall Environment" aka WinPE.

Comment: Thank you - that's another way to go that I forgot to mention. However apparently Acronis uses other method - just because you can't see Windows loading like Win PE. The main problem with Win PE for me is too long loading - it loads much slower than even the main OS.

Comment: @Isso: normally, WinPE loads quite quickly, certainly much faster than Windows itself.  Are you perhaps thinking of when it is booted from CD?  I believe the other common approach is to use a carefully cut down Linux or BSD distribution.

Comment: Harry, for me WinPE with no network support loads in about 25 sec if loaded from the main drive, or 40 sec when loaded from CD. With network support it takes 45 sec (main drive) and more than a minute (CD). Main system loads in only 12 sec. The machine is the same for all tests, clean install of Windows 7 x64, an i7 with SSD. Overall WinPE is quite acceptable to me, I was just wondering if there is any other faster solution like Acronis. And what is Acronis using in the end???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acronis actually boots into a Linux environment that runs from memory.  The GUI is provided by some version of XWindows using most likely a frame buffer device.  The UI toolkit they use was Fox Toolkit last time I checked.

When you exit it, it warm boots the machine to boot back into Windows.  So it's just another boot option, not a pre-boot option.  You could do the same, but creating a live Linux system isn't exactly easy.  You could also look at WinPE as someone suggested above, but there is a lot of licensing that comes with that.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you need is a bootloader.

How to develop your own Boot Loader : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36907/How-to-develop-your-own-Boot-Loader

Comment: I mentioned it in the my original post - the problem is the complexity of creating GUI for it

Answer (score 0):

First, if you're writing a program that runs before an OS boots, then you don't have an OS. So forget about things like "NT native app".

Writing such a program is very much like writing a program for DOS. DOS didn't provide any services for graphics, or windowing, or mouse input, or much of anything really (except disk access). You used to have to do all that stuff yourself (which is why graphical programs for DOS always looked a bit different from each other). There were toolkits that helped to build graphical interfaces, but I don't know whether any of those still exist today.

Even today, doing all your own graphical interface is still a lot of work. There might be one or two vendors who still provide GUI toolkits for such an application, but that sort of thing is going to be pretty rare. Only programs like partition editors and RAID controllers really need that today.

Comment: Graphical <strike>BIOS</strike> firmware setup is all the rage nowadays.  But he doesn't need "without an OS", he just needs to not boot the main OS install that's potentially in need of repair.

Comment: I agree that NT native app is strictly speaking not "booting before OS", however it allows to do necessary modifications to the system drive, that's why I mentioned it as a potential way to go. Sorry if I was unclear. Of course the obvious solution is build the GUI from scratch, but it's really lot of work, and considering that there are a bunch of similar programs on the market I'm pretty sure they use other approach, just because development of such UI may take even more time than the main functionality of their software.